# Validation rule formula for empty picklist field

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, picklist

I am trying to define a set of actions for a user based on salesforce picklists.

I have a main field called `fHCM2__Reason__c` that is a picklist containing multiple absence reason types - Sickness, Annual Leave etc

I then have a related field called `Annual_Leave_includes_a_trip_abroad__c` that is a picklist with two possible options - Yes or No

I want to define that if a user selects "Annual Leave" from the `fHCM2__Reason__c` picklist they cannot leave the field `Annual_Leave_includes_a_trip_abroad__c` blank and have to choose Yes or No.

Currently I have the below:

```
ISPICKVAL(fHCM2__Reason__c, "Annual Leave") 
&& ISBLANK(Annual_Leave_includes_a_trip_abroad__c)
```

My problem with my current method is that because `Annual_Leave_includes_a_trip_abroad__c` is a picklist, that has "Yes" or "No" options, this is causing an error as I cannot see how to define this in the above `PICKVAL()` statement.

Can anyone advise how can I state that if a user choose "Annual Leave" then they have to provide a value (Yes or No) for the `Annual_Leave_includes_a_trip_abroad__c` field if they choose Annual Leave?

Comment: For clarity, can you be more explicit about the fields in play, their types and, if they are picklists, the related values? Also, try to be as detailed as you can with the requirement.

Comment: @catalandres editied to try and make clearer what field types are involved and what outcome i am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

The function `ISBLANK()` takes an expression. A picklist needs to be "unpacked" with `TEXT()` to be considered an expression. Your validation rule should be:

```
ISPICKVAL(fHCM2__Reason__c, "Annual Leave") 
&& ISBLANK(TEXT(Annual_Leave_includes_a_trip_abroad__c))
```

[Source](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5) (see the section on `ISBLANK()`:

> If you use this function with a picklist, use ISBLANK(TEXT()) to
> convert the picklist items into a text value.

Bear in mind that if you are using this in a custom object (including a custom object that is part of a managed package released by Salesforce, like some parts of Health Cloud), you can use Dynamic Forms to render fields conditionally, and making the field to appear and be required when the right value of the initial picklist is selected, and hidden otherwise.

In general, it's a good idea to avoid creating validation rules when other alternatives that do not stop the users' flow are available.